# Building a PathGeometry from list of points without tons of other class creation

Tags: c#, pathgeometry

I am trying to build a simple polygonal PathGeometry from a custom list of points. I found the following code on the [msdn website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.pathgeometry(v=vs.110).aspx), and it appears to work fine, with a simple modification to loop and add LineSegments, but it seems like an awful amount of inelegant mess to do what seems to be a relatively simple task. Is there a better way?

```
PathFigure myPathFigure = new PathFigure();
myPathFigure.StartPoint = new Point(10, 50);

LineSegment myLineSegment = new LineSegment();
myLineSegment.Point = new Point(200, 70);

PathSegmentCollection myPathSegmentCollection = new PathSegmentCollection();
myPathSegmentCollection.Add(myLineSegment);

myPathFigure.Segments = myPathSegmentCollection;

PathFigureCollection myPathFigureCollection = new PathFigureCollection();
myPathFigureCollection.Add(myPathFigure);

PathGeometry myPathGeometry = new PathGeometry();
myPathGeometry.Figures = myPathFigureCollection;

Path myPath = new Path();
myPath.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
myPath.StrokeThickness = 1;
myPath.Data = myPathGeometry;
```

Comment: I don't believe that there is a better way, but you could wrap it in a function (such as `Path makePath(Point[] points)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap it in a function, and you can also consolidate some statements.

```
Path makePath(params Point[] points)
{
    Path path = new Path()
    {
        Stroke = Brushes.Black,
        StrokeThickness = 1
    };
    if (points.Length == 0)
        return path;

    PathSegmentCollection pathSegments = new PathSegmentCollection();
    for (int i = 1; i < points.Length; i++)
        pathSegments.Add(new LineSegment(points[i], true));

    path.Data = new PathGeometry()
    {
        Figures = new PathFigureCollection()
        {
            new PathFigure()
            {
                StartPoint = points[0],
                Segments = pathSegments
            }
        }
    };
    return path;
}
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
Path myPath = makePath(new Point(10, 50), new Point(200, 70));
```

Comment: Thanks, that works wonderfully! I modified it slightly to add a segment back to the start point, but that only matters if you are drawing it with some functions, as others don't seem to care.  
  
(Of course I didn't think to wrap it in a function. I obviously need more caffeine >.> )